# Pytesseract not keeping temp files on MacOS

Tags: macos, python-tesseract

When running

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '/usr/local/bin/tesseract'
img = cv2.imread('some.png')

h, w, c = img.shape
boxes = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(img)
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
File "/Users/thomaskilian/Documents/pytess.py", line 9, in <module>
  boxes = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(img)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 491, in image_to_boxes
  }[output_type]()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 490, in <lambda>
  Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 290, in run_and_get_output
  with open(filename, 'rb') as output_file:

builtins.FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/m3/26h8sdk11p7731577hpllh900000gn/T/tess_wayjir39.box'
```

I traced that down in pytesseract.py to

```
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
    filename = f"{kwargs['output_filename_base']}{extsep}{extension}"
    with open(filename, 'rb') as output_file:
```

After the `run` the output is in the temp `var` folder. But right at the `open` the file is gone. It just looks like the temp file is a bit too temporary. Can there anything be done?

Comment: Please add a proper [mcve]. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Well, I don't think it will reproduce the issue anywhere else (I added the code). It's probably something indirect :-/

Comment: Can you provide the following output ? print(tempfile.gettempdir())

Comment: @jacorl WHat would that help? I traced there and it's somewhere in the /var depth...

Comment: @jacorl btw you can see that path in the last line of the output quote above